# How to add div with dynamic id with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements, conditional-rendering

I am trying to create divs with Javascript:

```
var v = e[c].day;
        var m = g(new Date(t, n - 1, v))
          ? '<div id=`${v}/${v}/${y}` class="today" type="button" onclick="addRow()">'
          : '<div type="button" onclick="addRow()">';
        l.append(m + "" + '<span class="month">' + i[n-1]+ "</span>" + "" + v + "</div>");
```

So what I am trying to do is giving the id to the divs with the date and when I try to do like this **id=`${v}/${v}/${y}`** it is being written exactly like this: ${v}/${v}/${y} instead the date. So apparently, t is a year, n is a month and v is a day. So how can I give them an id like this `${v}/${v}/${y}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround the whole string with backticks:

```
`<div id="${v}/${v}/${y}" class="today" type="button" onclick="addRow()">`
```

See [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

Answer (score 1):

In the first output of your ternary statement it looks like you're returning the string using single quotes instead of backticks.

I suspect backticks is what you need:

```
var v = e[c].day;
        var m = g(new Date(t, n - 1, v))
          ? `<div id="${v}/${v}/${y}" class="today" type="button" onclick="addRow()">`
          : '<div type="button" onclick="addRow()">';
        l.append(m + "" + '<span class="month">' + i[n-1]+ "</span>" + "" + v + "</div>");
```

Comment: Using `${v}/${v}/${y}` doesn't make much sense for the date, does it?

Answer (score 0):

div is a closing tag that's why you must close every div in your code